# CodeDOM: Named Arguments

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to generate code for a constructor call. Something like

```
var obj = new Foo("bar", "baz", thirdParam: 5);
```

Part of my code:

```
var arg1 = new CodePrimitiveExpression("bar");
var arg2 = new CodePrimitiveExpression("baz");
var arg3 = new CodePrimitiveExpression(5);

var objectCreate = new CodeObjectCreateExpression(typeof(Foo), arg1, arg2, arg3);

var decl = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("var", "obj", objectCreate);
```

This is what is generated:

```
var obj = new Foo("bar", "baz", 5);
```

Is there any way (except from using CodeSnippetExpression) to create a named argument in CodeDOM?

Comment: You want to call a method/constructor with named argument using CodeDom or build a method/constructor with named parameter?

Comment: @AmirOveisi The former. The generated code should look like the first code line above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done using CodeDOM (without using a Code Snippet as you suggest). Named arguments are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) handled by the C# compiler.

Using CodeDOM you will need to provide a value for each parameter, even if it is `null`.